# Bidirectional use of Webclient for binary

Tags: asp.net, .net, silverlight, httpwebrequest, webclient

[Webclient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is used to upload an instruction file (up to 1 MegaByte) to the server an receives this manipulated instruction set as Response (up to 1 MegaByte) as binary data.

I am able to Upload binary and download binary but I am not able to do it with same request/response command. Means, not the same webclient can do this. In that case it looses the reference to the stream which was set on server.

[image: Webclient bidirectional binary example]

**How to write AND read binary data in one single sequence?**

.

**Server script**

```
Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

            'Setup data reader
            If cRead Is Nothing Then cRead = New ReadDataFromContext
            cRead.Read(context) 'read data from 'context.Request.InputStream'


            If cWrite Is Nothing Then cWrite = New WriteDataToContext
            cWrite.Write(context) 'write data to 'context.Response.OutputStream'


        End Sub
```

.

**Client class**

```
Partial Public Class MainPage
    Inherits UserControl
    Private WithEvents WCUpload As WebClient
    'Private WithEvents WCDownload As WebClient
    Private Stream As IO.Stream

    Dim U As New Uri("http://localhost:51001/communicator.ashx", UriKind.Absolute)


    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        WCUpload = New WebClient
        'WCDownload = New WebClient

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
        WCUpload.OpenWriteAsync(U)
    End Sub


    'This methode is never called if using WCUpload (on WCDownload it works but WCDownload has no more data)
    'Private Sub WC_OpenReadCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.Net.OpenReadCompletedEventArgs) Handles WCDownload.OpenReadCompleted
    '    Dim D(e.Result.Length - 1) As Byte
    '    e.Result.Read(D, 0, D.Length)
    '    Me.btnTest.Content = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(D, 0, D.Length)
    'End Sub

    Private Sub WC_OpenWriteCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.Net.OpenWriteCompletedEventArgs) Handles WCUpload.OpenWriteCompleted
        Me.Stream = e.Result

        Dim D() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hallo Timo")
        Me.Stream.Write(D, 0, D.Length)
        Me.Stream.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub WC_WriteStreamClosed(sender As Object, e As System.Net.WriteStreamClosedEventArgs) Handles WCUpload.WriteStreamClosed
        'WC.OpenReadAsync(U)

        'WCDownload.OpenReadAsync(U)

        Me.Stream.Position = 0 '<<--- ERROR, cannot access to disposed object
        Dim D(Me.Stream.Length - 1) As Byte
        Me.Stream.Read(D, 0, D.Length)
        Me.btnTest.Content = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(D, 0, D.Length)

    End Sub

    Public Sub PushData(ByVal StreamIn As IO.Stream, ByVal StreamOut As IO.Stream)
        Dim Buffer(4096 - 1) As Byte
        Dim BytesRead As Integer
        On Error Resume Next

        'RaiseEvent Progress(Me, 0)

        Do
            BytesRead = StreamIn.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)
            If BytesRead <= 0 Then Exit Do
            StreamOut.Write(Buffer, 0, BytesRead)
            'RaiseEvent Progress(Me, StreamOut.Length / StreamIn.Length * 99) 'max 99 to raise the event with 100%
        Loop

        'RaiseEvent Progress(Me, 100)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: When you say "same" request/response - are you looking to send a sequence of messages back and fore? Or...?

Comment: On server side I need to "manipulate" the data. And not create new file on server which I need to download with client. Just work in memory not file system. Perhaps I described not good and you can explain how to work without using filesystem-download methode for getting manipulated file back to client. Just request/response without changing the url.

Comment: "download" has nothing at all to do with files. If you use `UploadData` that sends a `byte[]` and fetches a `byte[]`. Isn't that everything you need?

Comment: I would be everything. But if I send bytes[] from client to server, the webclient class is no more able to download now anything FROM server. The only way is to create any second Webclient. But any second webclient cannot work with first request from first webclient.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to explain.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you are simply looking for the `UploadData` method, which sends a `byte[]` request-body to the server, and returns a `byte[]` response-body to the client. Simple as:

```
byte[] req = ...;
byte[] resp;
using(var client = new WebClient()) {
    resp = client.UploadData(address, req);
}
```

---

Ultimately, http is a request / response protocol - you can perform multiple requests sequentially, though. If you need more flexibility, I suggest you look at web-sockets which will allow both ends to send ad-hoc.

---

For async usage on silverlight, try the PCL version of HttpClient - similar api, but fuller implementation than silverlight offers out of the box: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx

Comment: Can you explain where you have found UploadData? And also how to manage this asynchronous?

Comment: @Nasenbaer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.net.webclient.uploaddata.aspx (And UploadDataAsync in .NET 4.5.)