# Use HttpResponse to upload data in Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, httprequest, httpresponse

How to use asynchronous bidirectional binary upload and download of data in Silverlight?

1. I need to upload my binary file to the server and then >
2. Get the answer also as binary file from server

My current sample I am using is this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.begingetresponse.aspx

But the sample starts with a request and I need to start with upload.

I've tried with WebClient but there I am not able to do up-/download in one sequence: [Bidirectional use of Webclient for binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981496/bidirectional-use-of-webclient-for-binary)

Comment: You do realize that using two `WebClient` and/or two `WebRequest` objects at the same time is the same as the idea you are playing with (of having one be bi-directional)?

Comment: No it is not the same, because I have not the same Uri (it is using hash syntax) I am able to use. If I will upload binary, I don't know where to download in other webclient because I have no response object to work with. Or I misunderstand.

Answer (score 2):

I did is synchronous by Handlers.(ASHX) in Silverlight.RadFileUploader is a Telerik 's component works with these handlers.

```
  namespace MyNameSpace.Web
    {   
      public class FileHandler : IHttpHandler
           {

      public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
      {

        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {

            string fileName = context.Request.QueryString.Get("fileName");

            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {                 
                context.Response.ContentType = MimeType(fileName);
                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
                context.Response.WriteFile(fileName, 0, length);
            }
          }
   }
```

I cut most of the code but it gives the idea.
I used a handler to play audio files and a handler to download audio file.  Mimetype is very important part. Also your headers are important. By this way you tell what you want to do.

For asynchronous this page may help. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433(v=vs.100).aspx

**EDIT**

The below handler file reads a file `"Top.jasper"` from a directory and write it on the callback method. `(ar.IsCompleted)` argument's IsCompleted property checks if its completed.

`<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind="BDTest.ashx.cs" Class="AHBSBus.Web.Classes.BDTest" %>`

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Threading;
     using System.IO;

    namespace AHBSBus.Web.Classes
     {
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for BDTest
/// </summary>
public class BDTest : IHttpAsyncHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }


    public BDTest()
    {

    }
    public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
    {
        cb = new AsyncCallback((ar) =>
            {

                if (ar.IsCompleted)
                {
                    var result = ar.AsyncState;

                    File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\new.jasper", (byte[])result);
                }
            });

        extraData = File.ReadAllBytes("c:\\Top.jasper");

        context.Response.Write("<p>Begin IsThreadPoolThread is " + Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread + "</p>\r\n");
        AsynchOperation asynch = new AsynchOperation(cb, context, extraData);
        asynch.StartAsyncWork();
        return asynch;
    }

    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var ctx=context;
    }
}

class AsynchOperation : IAsyncResult
{
    private bool _completed;
    private Object _state;
    private AsyncCallback _callback;
    private HttpContext _context;

    bool IAsyncResult.IsCompleted { get { return _completed; } }
    WaitHandle IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle { get { return null; } }
    Object IAsyncResult.AsyncState { get { return _state; } }
    bool IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously { get { return false; } }

    public AsynchOperation(AsyncCallback callback, HttpContext context, Object state)
    {
        _callback = callback;
        _context = context;
        _state = state;
        _completed = false;
    }

    public void StartAsyncWork()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(StartAsyncTask), null);
    }

    private void StartAsyncTask(Object workItemState)
    {
        //You may modify _state object here            
        _context.Response.Write("<p>Completion IsThreadPoolThread is " + Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread + "</p>\r\n");

        _context.Response.Write("Hello World from Async Handler!");
        _completed = true;
        _callback(this);
    }
  }
 }
```

I offer `SignalR` for bidirectional comms.

Comment: Thank for answer. But it does not solve the problem as I see. After `context.Response.WriteFile(fileName, 0, length);` it will write the file to the harddisk but it does not send binary data back to the client, right? I need to receive binary and answer binary in one task.

Comment: It writes the data to enduser's browser not to disk!

Answer (score 2):

AHSX is the way to Go, but with special consideration for files that exceed 4 MB.

What you will need to put in place Two things :

- Server Side : Ashx HttpHandler that will handle the data received :

  public class FileUpload : IHttpHandler
  {
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
      {
          _httpContext = context;

  ```
      if (context.Request.InputStream.Length == 0)
          throw new ArgumentException("No file input");

      try
      {
          // Method that will be populating parameters from HttpHandler Request.
          GetQueryStringParameters();

          string uploadFolder = _directory;
          string tempFileName = _fileName + _tempExtension;

          if (_firstChunk)
          {
              //// Delete temp file
              if (File.Exists(@HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "/" + uploadFolder + "/" + tempFileName))
                  File.Delete(@HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "/" + uploadFolder + "/" + tempFileName);

              //// Delete target file
              if (File.Exists(@HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "/" + uploadFolder + "/" + _fileName))
                  File.Delete(@HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "/" + uploadFolder + "/" + _fileName);

          }



          using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "/" + uploadFolder + "/" + tempFileName, FileMode.Append))
          {
              SaveFile(context.Request.InputStream, fs);
              fs.Close();
          }

          if (_lastChunk)
          {
              File.Move(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "/" + uploadFolder + "/" + tempFileName, HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "/" + uploadFolder + "/" + _fileName);
          }


      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          // Todo
          // Logger Exception
          throw;
      }

  }
  ```

  }
- the Silverlight class that will invoke it :

public class UploadFile
    {

public void Upload(Stream streamNewFile, string fileName, string dirOnServer = "")
        {
            this.uploadMode = UploadMode.OpenStream;

```
        this.destinationOnServer = dirOnServer;
        this.fileStream = streamNewFile;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.dataLength = this.fileStream.Length;

        long dataToSend = this.dataLength - this.dataSent;
        bool isLastChunk = dataToSend <= this.chunkSize;
        bool isFirstChunk = this.dataSent == 0;
        string docType = "document";

        var strCurrentHost = HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.ToString().Substring(0, HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.ToString().LastIndexOf('/'));
        UriBuilder httpHandlerUrlBuilder = new UriBuilder(strCurrentHost + "/FileUpload.ashx");
        httpHandlerUrlBuilder.Query = string.Format("{5}file={0}&offset={1}&last={2}&first={3}&docType={4}&destination={6}",
            fileName, this.dataSent, isLastChunk, isFirstChunk, docType,
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpHandlerUrlBuilder.Query) ? string.Empty : httpHandlerUrlBuilder.Query.Remove(0, 1) + "&", destinationOnServer);

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(httpHandlerUrlBuilder.Uri);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(this.WriteToStreamCallback), webRequest);
    }
```

}

Comment: That is how to upload any file, right? I am exact on this stage but I am now to able to send the silverlight client any binary data back rightnow. Not a second URL and second request. Can you expand your example? After your server class says: `fs.close()` it should send the same file now back to the client as demo?

Comment: Actually, i didn't send binary data back to client. have you got a look at WCF Pooling Duplex ?  Else ; Wcf can make streaming to target silverlight Client : check it here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/07/08/using-transfermode-streamedresponse-to-download-files-in-silverlight-4.aspx